# fprintf fails on specific string while shell functions use it with no crash

Tags: c++, printf, echo

***The short version: I have a C++ code that uses a C call to `fprintf(stdout, some_cpp_str.c_str())` and crashes during it. The first 4 calls are fine, only the 5th crashes, and I have no idea why <sub>(suspecting unreadable char inside the string)</sub>. The 1st code I posted was mostly C, so I posted another one, with only C++ except for the `fprintf` (code added at the bottom of the question). The crashes occur (consistently) on an embedded device. On my own PC the code runs fine***

---

***The long version:***

I have a code that reads lines from text, and pushes them into a string vector. TO check my progress, I also `fprintf` them to the screen after the vector is populated:

```
int main(){
    char    err_msg[256], * line = NULL, *in_file = "...", *keyword = "blah";
    size_t  len = 0;
        ssize_t num_bytes_read;
    int i = 1;
    std::vector<std::string> lines_vector;

    FILE * fp = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stdout,"can't open file %s for reading\n", in_file);
        goto EXIT;
    }

    while ((num_bytes_read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        /* if found keyword inside line */
        if (strstr(line, keyword)) {
            /* add 3 lines (entry heading, entry body, newline)*/
            lines_vector.push_back(std::string(line));
            for(int lines_to_copy = 2; lines_to_copy > 0; lines_to_copy--) {
                if((num_bytes_read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) == -1) {
                    fprintf(stdout,"can't read line from %s\n", in_file);
                    goto EXIT;
                }
                lines_vector.push_back(std::string(line));
            }
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"finished reading from file\n");

EXIT:
    fclose(fp);
    free(line);

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = lines_vector.begin() ; it != lines_vector.end(); ++it, ++i) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d)", i);
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", (*it).c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This works fine on my VM, but I also run it on an embedded device, where it always crashes on a specific line. The line is:

`certificates local generate name localcert common-name sf country(region) AB auto-regenerate-days 12  auto-regenerate-days-warning 11  e-mail X@Y.com  locality(city) Z organization Q organization-unit T scep-password-string 57E6CA35452E72E4D1BC4518260ABFC7  scep-url http://0.0.0.0/X/Y/  state(province) s`

I don't think there is a problem in the line itself (as it doesn't crash on my VM). When trying to print it to a file instead of to the screen, it doesn't crash:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = lines_vector.begin(); it != lines_vector.end(); ++it){
    sprintf(tmp, "echo \"%s\" >> /X/Y/Z.txt", (*it).c_str());
    OS_run(tmp);  // run this command on sh shell
}
```

Since it crashes only on my embedded and not my VM, I thought the file is somehow corrupted. Could it be that the string has an invalid char inside that crashes `fprintf`, but not `echo`?

---

I tried translating this code into proper C++, but I still get a crash in the middle of the last string. I know mixing C/C++ is not good, but shouldn't `c_str()` be a proper interface between `std::string` and char * (which `fprintf` expects)?

If not this, then what could possibly crash during the `fprintf`?

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> lines_vector;
    std::ifstream infile(in_file);
    std::string line;
    int counter = 1;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))  {
        if (line.find(keyword, 0) != std::string::npos) {
            lines_vector.push_back(line);
            for(int lines_to_copy = 2; lines_to_copy > 0; lines_to_copy--)  {
                std::getline(infile, line);
                lines_vector.push_back(line);
            }
        }
    }

    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = lines_vector.begin(); it != lines_vector.end(); ++it){
        fprintf(stdout, "%d)%s", counter++, (*it).c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: You lost me at "The is".  Those getline() calls look very unhealthy, if the first argument is not NULL then it assumes you allocated a buffer yourself.  You didn't.

Comment: You lost me at `printf()` in the title of a C++ question. ;-) Seriously though. Pick one language, and then *go* with that language. The mix of C and C++ you're showing here is positively unhealthy, and forfeits most of the advantages C++ can give you. `FILE *`? And `goto`?

Comment: the getline syntax appears to be correct, as the buffer pointer is properly initialized to 0. Is the memory on the device too limited ? What you describe is what we would expect if getline was unable to realloc a larger buffer when needed. I suggest you try using a large enough preallocated buffer (e.g. `line = malloc(len=4096);` before the first getline) and test it on the embedded device.

Comment: @HansPassant the getline part is copied from man.

Comment: If it always crashes on a specific line, does it still crash when you just hard-code that line and take out all the line-reading loop code? If so, _that_ is your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you can't reproduce it without the line-reading code, presumably that's doing something wrong. Have you turned on warnings? Have you run with valgrind or an address sanitizer?

Comment: Really. This isn't the getline() you're looking for. [This is.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: @DevSolar for a `FILE *` stream, this is exactly the getline he wants, the C one.

Comment: @FBergo: Yes, but why *would* you use a `FILE *` stream *in C++*? There is no legacy API requirement I can see. So the answer is, you don't, you learn about `<iostream>` and use code that is more robust, more expressive, type-safe, and shorter...

Comment: @FBergo the crash is always in the `fprintf` line, not the `getline` line, so the buffer size is not the problem

Comment: @CIsForCookies: How would you know? Undefined behaviour is undefined...

Comment: @DevSolar but what is undefined here? very unorthodox / very unhealthy / abomination maybe, but I don't see where I violate here any rules

Comment: OT: Consider using `lines_vector.emplace_back(line);`

Comment: Apart from being hard to read because of the heavy use of C-ish code, I cannot see a true reason for a crash, except a flaw in the embedded implementation. But you should show your included headers and say what compiler/system is used for the embedded device (including version and compilation switches)

Comment: @AndersK. yes. Tried that with a buffer size of 1024 (while the longest line in the text file is about 400 chars)

Comment: In the man for `getline` I read *"return -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-file condition).  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the cause."*. Have you checked errno?

Comment: This is a long shot, but on very old GCCs (pre-4.x) on embedded non-X86 architectures, I've seen goto jumps (mis)compiled in ways that mishandle the stack and leave it corrupted when jumping off loops. Next thing to try would be removing the goto's (this is not a critique on style, but an actual issue for some not-so-mainstream architectures and bad compilers).

Comment: Updated the Q. Tried using only C++, but the question still remains - what could be the problem in using `fprintf` with a `c_str()`'d string?

Comment: Is your compiler at least C++11 standard compliant? I'm asking because, if I remember correctly, [`std::basic_string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) guarantees the null-terminator only since then.

Comment: @Bob__ I'll check that tomorrow. If that is the case, I can `fprintf(stdout, "%d)%s%s", counter++, (*it).c_str(), "");`, no?

Comment: If that is the case, try `fprintf(stdout, "%d)%.*s", counter++, (int)it->length(), it->c_str());`. I'd also write the inner loop as `for(int lines = 2; lines > 0 && std::getline(infile, line); lines--)  {lines_vector.push_back(line);}`. Please remember that, unlike POSIX getline, std::getline does not copy the newline char.

Comment: @Bob__ your `printf(stdout, "%d)%.*s", counter++, (int)it->length(), it->c_str());` also crashed :-(

Comment: I'd suggest to add infos about the embedded device itself and the compiler you are using. Also, about your concerns about the "unreadable"(non-printable?) chars in the string, you could just inspect the values. The last string is the bigger one? Have you tried flushing the output stream?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176243/discussion-between-cisforcookies-and-bob).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an embedded device, you can expect that dynamic memory allocation fail. That means that you absolutely must control all possible allocations (you should anyway even on non embedded device, but the crash risk is much lower...). You really should have:

```
while ((num_bytes_read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    ...
}
if (line == NULL) {
    perror("getline could not allocate buffer");
}
```

This will not fix anything, but at least you will know what happens.

---

I have respected your coding style here, making heavy use of the C library and also using `goto`. But I must advise you not to do that in C++ programs.

C library used to be included in C++ standard library because early C++ implementations were lacking too many functionalities. In modern C++ `goto` is to be banned, as are all raw C strings and C io functions (except in very special use cases). And C++ come with a version of `getline` (in header `<string>`) that directly fills a `std::string`. You really should try to avoid C construct if learning C++.

---

Per Ben Voigt's comment, there are correct use case to use old style C library if you want to avoid dynamic allocation. But in that case, you should also avoid `std::string` and `std::vector`

Comment: if the allocation failed, that would have happen inside `getline`, so the return value of it should have been -1, wouldn't it?

Comment: If dynamic allocation doesn't work, then neither does `std::string` nor any of the C++ niceties you recommend.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I do not know whether modern C++ can be recommended on an embedded system. What I mean is that not testing dynamic allocation error when it can happen can lead to weird behaviour. OP and not I decided to use `std::vector`. And I would expect all C++ goodies to immediately terminate on exception if they cannol allocate... Anyway, your remark makes sense and I have edited my answer.